# TypeError: moment(...).tz is not a function

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this js code:

```
toolFilters.filter('dateAccordingToTimeZone', function($filter) {
    // Gets the number of milliseconds pass from 1970 and convert it to time according to given timezone, currently
    // supported “Asia/Jerusalem” and “America/Los_Angeles”
    return function(milliSeconds, timeZoneId) {
        if (milliSeconds == 0) {
            return "";
        }

        return moment().tz(milliSeconds, timeZoneId).format('MMM d, y H:mm:ss z');  // 5am PDT

    };
})
```

and this html

```
<script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
```

after installing via bower

but i get this error:

```
VM9216:1 Uncaught TypeError: moment(...).tz is not a function
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (filters.js:31), <anonymous>:1:10)
    at filters.js:31
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15551), <anonymous>:4:485)
    at regularInterceptedExpression (angular.js:16658)
    at expressionInputsWatch (angular.js:16579)
```

how can i fix this?

as I based on the [official doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

just without the "require" as I use native js

moment().format();

Comment: I followed the docs. that's why i'm asking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moment Timezone is a separate module, that needs to be installed in addition to moment.
See the [document](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) to see how to install it.

Demo **without** `tz` module:

```js
moment().tz();
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
</script>
```

Demo **with** `tz` module:

```js
moment().tz();
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Okay the you need to import it in addition to `moment`, will edit my answer.

Comment: It fails parsing my tz format even though it was supposed to support according to documentation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50088484/how-to-use-moment-tz-js-to-parse-tz-like-gmt-0800

Comment: Running code snippet gives a moment(...).tz is not a function error in console log