# How to use moment-tz.js to parse tz like "GMT-08:00"

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I try to run this js

```
return function(milliSeconds, timeZoneId) {
    if (milliSeconds == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    var now = moment();

    return now.tz(timeZoneIdm, milliSeconds).format('MMM d, yyyy H:mm:ss'); 
}
```

For example with this input:

```
milliSeconds = "1524578400000"

timezoneId = "GMT-08:00"
```

it fails for parsing `"GMT-08:00"`. Anyway can I adjust it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [`moment.tz(..., String)`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) docs states:

> The moment.tz constructor takes all the same arguments as the `moment` constructor, but uses the last argument as a [time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

A *time zone identifier* is something like `'America/New_York'` or `'Europe/Rome'`, `"GMT-08:00"` is not a valid input.

In your case you can use [`moment(Number)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) and then:

- converting to given zone using [`tz()`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) function
- or set offset using [`utcOffset(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/)

```js
var milliSeconds = "1524578400000";
var timezoneId = "GMT-08:00";

var timeInt = parseInt(milliSeconds, 10)
var m1 = moment(timeInt).tz('America/Los_Angeles');
console.log(m1.format('MMM D, YYYY H:mm:ss'));

var offset = timezoneId.substring(3);
var m2 = moment(timeInt).utcOffset(offset);
console.log(m2.format('MMM D, YYYY H:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Please note that:

- moment [formatting](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) tokens are case sensitive, so you have to use `YYYY` for years and `D` for day of the month (`d` is day of the week)
- `1524578400000` is `2018-04-24 14:00:00` UTC, I'm missing why you are expecting `5am` as output.

Comment: I actually had to change the signature as `moment.tz(..., String)`  threw a runtime exception. seems the first arg should be the tz

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on similar topic and got answer to your original question. Hope will help other people if this is too late to you.

First of all, just like @VincenzoC explained:
1. Have to change the Unix timestamp to 10-digit for Moment.JS. 
2. The format for year should be "YYYY" instead of "yyyy".

Per the explanation here [enter link description here](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/)
 POSIX compatibility requires that the offsets are inverted. Therefore, Etc/GMT-X will have an offset of +X and Etc/GMT+X will have an offset of -X. This is a result of IANA's Time Zone Database and not an arbitrary choice by Moment.js.

You need to change set as:
var timezoneId = "Etc/GMT+08";
Then run 
moment.unix(1524578400).tz("Etc/GMT+8").format('MMM d, YYYY H:mm:ss Z');

The return is:  "Apr 2, 2018 6:00:00 -08:00"
Please note what you expect is 5am but it's Day light saving time, so the return is 6am which is correct.